# Is there any way to speed up app packages generation in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp

It's been taking around 40 minutes or more to generate app packages for Windows UWP application using Visual studio 2015 update 2. My CPU looks pretty maxed out during most of the process too. I have all three types of architecture checked off at the beginning of the process (x86, x64, and ARM) and include PDB files checked as well. I don't know if this is normal or not, but I really need to know if there is a way to make this process faster? Is it dependant on my computer, like if I get a better CPU and memory will it help?  Are there any other tips to make it faster?

My hardware = (Win 10, Intel i5 2500K, 3.3GHz, 12GB RAM)

**EDIT**: This is the configuration window

[image]

Comment: what the configuration mode you use?

Comment: @AndriiKrupka For each architecture, I chose Release (is that what you meant?)

Comment: so, I can suggest to unlink .Net Native for test Release 'package' and use .Net Native only when you create build for store. because it's really hard proccess.

Comment: Here is what I recommend: when you build and test your package make sure you do enable .NET Native. When you are ready to publish to the store, you can use a build flag by building on the command line with msbuild.exe: /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode="CI"; this should skip the .NET Native compilation but still produce a valid .appxupload. Make sure you always test .NET Native before your publish though.